# Recursive function in javascript and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I'm trying to do a little web in JavaScript + Ajax and I want to do it recursively. I've never used ajax before and the problem is I don't know to finish functions. The code looks like that:

```
var cont = 0;
var function1 = function (query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: {
                .
                .
                .
        },
        success: function (response) {
            instructions;
            function2(param1, param2);
        }
    });
};
var function2 = function (query, param2) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: {
                .
                .
                .
        },
        success: function (response) {
            instructions;
            function3(param1, param2, param3);
        }
    });
};
var function3 = function (query, param2, param3) {
    if (cont == 2) {
        console.log("finish");
        return;
    }
    var test = $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: {
                .
                .
                .
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (...) {
                cont++;
                instructions;
                var audio = new Audio(...);
                audio.play();
                audio.onended = function () {
                    instructions;
                    function3(query, param2, param3);
                    return;
                };
            } else {
                instructions;
                function3(query, param2, param3);
            };
            return;
        }
    });
    return;
};
document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    function1(document.getElementById('query').value);
}, false);
```

So basically, when `cont == 2`I try to get out of javascript `function3` with `return;` but some part of the program ( I don't know if the `success: function (response)` or the full javascript `function3` ) is still running and instructions are being executed.

How could I solve this?

Comment: If your if conditional doesn't pass as true three times, `cont` will never be `2`.

Comment: Where do the `paramX` values comes from? You could put them all in an array and pass them recursively to a single function.

Comment: it always reaches 2, that's not the problem

Comment: If it reaches 2, then the function will return.  What does the call stack look like then?  I would use FireBug to set a breakpoint there and see what each function will do as the last one on the stack returns.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, assuming `cont` eventually reaches 2.

Comment: I put a setInterval inside ajax succes function to console.log('HelloWorld') every 3 seconds. When cont = 2 it still keeps logging 'HelloWorld'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the way to do this properly is to make use of jQuery's deferred objects.

As you have probably noticed, the program doesn't simply wait at the ajax request, and then proceed to the 'success' handler. This is because Javascript uses a non-blocking/waiting model. So you call $.ajax({params,...}), this sends the request, but whatever's after this will then immediately run, without waiting. Then, once the top level function has finished executing and nothing else is running, the response can be processed, and the 'success' handler is invoked.

So how to do this stuff properly? Start by arranging your request functions like this:

```
function doRequest1() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: {
                .
                .
                .
        }
    });
}

function doRequest2(parameter) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: {
                .
                p: parameter
                .
        }
    });
}
```

Notice that we aren't providing a success handler, but we are returning the value that $.ajax returns. This is a deferred object which is used to represent a request which has been sent, but for which a response hasn't been received/handled. You can attach a handler to the object like this:

```
var r1 = doRequest1();

r1.then(function() {
    // Do stuff on success...
});
```

A nice thing about these objects is that they can be chained using 'then'.
'then' accepts a function which takes the value of the old request and produces a new request to do next:

```
var allRequests = doRequest1().then(function(result1) {
    return doRequest2("hello");
});
```

The 'allRequests' variable is now a deferred object representing the result of doRequest2. How do you get this result? You use 'then()', just like any other deferred:

```
allRequests.then(function(result) {
    alert("All requests completed. Result of last one: " + result);
});
```

Make sure that you understand how the result from 1 request can be used to set the parameters for the next one, or even decide which request to make next.

If you don't need one request's result to determine the next, rather, you just want to run a number of requests and wait for them all to complete, you can use a shortcut, 'when':

```
$.when(doRequest1(),doRequest2(), doRequest3()).then(function(result1,result2,result3) {
    // All done
});
```

Another nice thing about deferreds is that they can be cancelled:

```
allRequests.abort();
```

Using the above, hopefully you can see how to restructure your code so you get a sequence of requests with a function to run after all 3 have completed.

Answer (score -1):

Watch the value of your global variable `cont` through the flow of your program.  It may be that it is (never) equal to 2 when `function3()` is called and that is why your program continues.

Comment: it always reaches 2, that's not the problem